# php natural case insensitive sort of url encoded strings

Tags: php

the php function `natcasesort` sort characters in natural languages and case insensitive. The problem is if your array is using url encoded characters. In those cases the encoded (%nn, like %E4) character is sorted before the letter "a", although it is expected in this case to sort after the letter "z".

Our code is like:

```
/* set internal character encoding as on page */
mb_internal_encoding("ISO-8859-1");
ob_start("mb_output_handler");
...
$dir_array[] = "<a href=\"$webdirname/$file_url\"target=_blank>$file_date</a>";
...
function put_array_vertical($input, $size, $sortByname = true, $size_is_horizontal = true, $rowSize = 740) 
{
   ...
   natcasesort($input);
   ...
}
?>

<td width="100%" valign="top" class="mfo-link">
   <?=put_array_vertical($dir_array, $inColumns, true, true, 740)?>
</td>
```

Is there any simple way around this problem?

Character set is expected to be iso-8859-1 in all places. Had to specify that in the php script as it in later versions defaults to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own sorting routine:

```
usort ($input , function($a, $b) { return natstrcmp(urldecode($a), urldecode($b)) });
```